# Regex to match css key value string

Tags: javascript, css, regex, pattern-matching, regex-greedy

I am using regex to match css values.

Input string to match

```
 font-size:25px;font-family:georgian;content:"' unicode given in pseudo &#169; '";
```

Regex I am using to match

```
/.*\bcontent:(\s*[^;]*)/
```

I am using $1 to get the actual string output of regex

Expected output is **"' unicode given in pseudo &#169** '"**

But actual is **"' unicode given in pseudo &#169**

Because regex finds `;` in the content value so it breaks there.
So how can i fix this bug.
Ideally regex should look for the last `;` which is not inside the double/single quotes. Because my input string will always have `;` after each property value ends.

Thanks

Comment: Try `/.*\bcontent:\s*(.*);/` to match up to the last `;` char on a line. Or just `/\bcontent:\s*"([^"]*)";/` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/bNddSL/1))

Comment: Try `\bcontent:\s*(".*?");`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/p0thRU/3).

Answer (score 2):

Simplify it: Take the piece of text within quotes:

```
/.*\bcontent:(\"[^\"]*\")/
```

Comment: If one wants to simplify the pattern, one would omit `.*` in the pattern. As in my comment, it is enough  to use `/\bcontent:("[^"]*")/` (I just placed the capturing group inside the quotes to exclude them from the match).

Comment: its failing for this case content:"'@@@@@@@@@@@@@ '","'@@@@@@@@@@@@@&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@'","'@@@@@@@@@@@@@&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@'";

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This works but not for all the cases.Ideally regex should look for the last ; which is not inside the double/single quotes. Because my input string will always have ; after each property value ends.

Comment: @Pavan, of course it fails, there's no 'content' in your string.

Comment: @PavanTiwari You cannot get an undefined number of quoted substrings until the first non-quoted semicolon with a regular expression. You need to code an specific **parser** for that matter.

Comment: @PoulBak I am not sure for which string you are talking about because all the sample strings contains content:

Comment: The eaxmple, you showed in comment does not contain the string 'content'.